# How can I make Google sheets automatically remove a blank in my list

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to create a list in google sheets that would automatically move the items every time I remove one? Basically what I want is for all the items in the list to be in a row without a blank cell. Something like this:[image: example]

I am new to google sheets and I tried just sorting the list but #1 I dont want it sorted and #2 Id like for it to happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=tocol(A2:A,1)
```

***OR***

```js
=filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")
```